# VSCode can't find typescript type declarations for some part three.js

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, type-declaration

The code work just fine but I'm getting an annoying warning and I want to get rid of it. I have no idea why its there. I've used three.js in other projects and it worked just fine.
I did `npm i -D @types/three` as usual but it didn't fix my problem so I out of ideas.

EDIT:
[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtBLg.png)

The version of three.js in package.json `"three": "^0.151.3"`

Comment: Please post the warning-text and also the lines of code, the warning is referring to.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. minimal code to reproduce the issue, the error message, what exact version of three you have installed (`npm list three`), and what exact version of the types package you have installed (`npm list @types/three`).

Comment: [Please post the code and warning as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). The link to a picture is fine for illustration, but it's important for us to have the text itself. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.